# Angular 9 : How do I get the properties of an object returned from a rest api service call

Tags: angular

I am writing an app using Angular 9, and I'm new to it.  I have written a service API to get data, but I'm having trouble understanding how to get data from my service call into an Angular component.

Here is an example object in **endcustomer.ts**:

```
export interface IEndCustomer {
  endCustomerId: number;
  endCustomerName: string;
  fein: string;
```

Here is where I call my REST API in **endcustomer.service.ts**:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core'
import { HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { IEndCustomer } from './endcustomer';
import { Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

export class EndCustomerService {
  private APIurl2 = "https://localhost:44331/api/endcustomer/GetEndCustomerById";

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getEndCustomerById(id) {
    return this.http.get<IEndCustomer>(this.APIurl2 + "/" + id);
}
```

And this is where I try to create a form using the details of one end customer, in **endcustomer_detail.component.ts**:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { IEndCustomer } from './endcustomer';
import { EndCustomerService } from './endcustomer.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'endcustomer',
  templateUrl: './endcustomer_detail.component.html'
})

export class EndCustomerDetailComponent implements OnInit {
  pageTitle: string = 'Customer Detail'
  customer: IEndCustomer;
constructor(private endcustomerService: EndCustomerService) { }

 ngOnInit() {
    let id = +this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');

    this.endcustomerService.getEndCustomerById(id).subscribe({
      next: customer => {
        this.customer.endCustomerId = customer.endCustomerId;
        this.customer.endCustomerName = customer.endCustomerName;
        this.customer.fein = customer.fein;
  }
}
```

The problem is that I get an error message that "Property 'endCustomerId' does not exist on type 'unknown', with a squiggly red line under the property: this.customer.endCustomerId = customer.**endCustomerId**.  I do not understand why customer is listed as 'unknown'.

If I try "**this.customer.endCustomerId** = customer;", then the error reads "Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'number'.

If I try "**this.customer** = customer;" then the error reads "Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'IEndCustomer': endCustomerId, endCustomerName, fein"

I tried a number of different things because the examples on the Internet all seem to be organized a little differently, but I'm just not getting it.  Can someone explain what I am doing wrong and if there is a better way to do get the properties of my returned object so that I can have an endCustomer, which I can then use on the html page to display the ID and name please?

Comment: What is the result of this?
this.endcustomerService.getEndCustomerById(id).subscribe( data=>{console.log(data)});

Comment: data has the properties for my endCustomer that are returned from the service.  So the data is coming back but I have a few things messed up with how I handle it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens if you compile the code? It may compile without any errors. From what I understand, these may be TS Lint errors.

If you wish to remove the squiggly red lines, try the following

Service

```js
getEndCustomerById(id): Observable<IEndCustomer> {   // <-- mention return type
  return this.http.get<IEndCustomer>(this.APIurl2 + "/" + id);
}
```

Component

```js
ngOnInit() {
  let id = +this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
  this.endcustomerService.getEndCustomerById(id).subscribe(
    customer => { this.customer = customer },
    error => { // always good practice to handle HTTP errors }
  );
}
```

Comment: When I add a return type to the service the line with the code is highlighted with an error: "Type 'Observable<unknown> is not assignable to type 'Observable<IEndCustomer>'.  Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'IEndCustomer': endCustomerId, endCustomerName, fein.  I am not sure what TS Lint errors are, but these seem to be bigger issues than I can ignore.

Comment: But ignoring those TS Lint errors, when I change the service and component code as you suggested, my detail page shows the data.  Thank you!

Comment: You could learn more about TS Linter in VS Code here: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/typescript#_linters

Answer (score 1):

Hi there in order this function to work you nned to use lambda function.

So convert your subscription to

```
 this.endcustomerService.getEndCustomerById(id).subscribe(customer=>{
    this.customer.endCustomerId = customer.endCustomerId;
    this.customer.endCustomerName = customer.endCustomerName;
    this.customer.fein = customer.fein;
})
```

The problem with the syntax you provided is that results in a context change and since there is not such ojbejct as customer in the other context it wil result in null

Comment: I changed this code and there was still an error in the compiler that says the property does not exist on unknown.  When I run the site and try to open this page, I get an error in the console that says ERROR TypeError: Cannot set property 'endCustomerId' of undefined and points to that line of the TypeScript file.

Comment: It turned out that I needed to define the return type on the service.  Thank you!